# need help understanding slope of tangent

Tags: derivatives

For the function
$$y = 6x^2 + 9x + 9$$
at the point  $x = 6$, find the following.

(a) the slope of the tangent to the curve

(b) the instantaneous rate of change of the function

I have tried doing $279-204$ over $x=6 - x=5$ and $366-29$ over $x=7-x=6$ and not sure what to do next.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: tried 279-204 over x=6 - x=5  and 366-29 over x=7-x=6 and not sure what to do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to calculate is the average rate of change of the function (also called slope of secant) between $x=5$ and $x=6$.

Both slope of tangent and instantaneous rate of change of the function are given by the value of the derivative at $x=6$.$$y'(x)=12x+9\Big|_{x=6}=12(6)+9=81$$